# How do you validate that PropTypes of a component in ReactJS are mutually inclusive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I define the PropTypes for a component that takes in PropTypes that are required together or not required at all?

For example:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.linkTo = this.linkTo.bind(this);
    }

    linkTo(url) {
        return () => {
            this.props.linkTo(url);
        }
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            {this.props.title}
            { this.props.link &&
            <button onClick={this.linkTo(this.props.link)}>Go!</button>
            }
        </div>
    }
}

Example.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    link: React.PropTypes.string,
    linkTo: React.PropTypes.func
};
```

If we don't specify either `link` or `linkTo` as props, just `title` will be rendered. However, if we specify `link`, then we need `linkTo` to be passed from the parent too and vice versa.

Comment: Why not accept link and linkTo as a part of one object and make that required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom propType function that checks other props.

```
function propRelatedOr(otherProp, propType){
  return (props, propName, componentName) => {
    if (props[propName] == null && props[otherProp] == null) {
      return new Error(`In ${componentName} expected either prop ${propName} or ${otherProp} to exist`);
    }
    if (propType) { 
      return propType(props, propName, componentName);
    }
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Example.propTypes = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    link: propRelatedOr('linkTo', React.PropTypes.string),
    linkTo: propRelatedOr('link', React.PropTypes.func),
};
```

You can create versions of the function that do 'and', 'xor', etc.

Comment: Thanks that really helped to create some custom prop types.